# How to change the GUI of a website via Google Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am currently working on a project, that when installed from the Google Chrome webstore, it would replace the Google Drive's GUI, with a custom one. Also it would use the same custom GUI in a external Window (this utilizes the Offline feature of Drive). I am wondering on how to use my custom GUI, and replace the Google Drive's one.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. What have you tried so far? Which documentation have you read? What does this have to do with Chrome Apps (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps)?

Comment: Ok, I am attempting to use a Custom HTML page that I designed, and when a user navigates to 'drive.google.com' it will load up the custom HTML page I designed, instead of Google's.